# Unable to search for directory using isdir when folder name had on numeric using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating folder after checking non-existence of folder with same name. However I am unable to check for the folder using `isdir` if folder name contains only numbers.

```
>>> print(os.path.isdir('D:\Git_File\IAutomation\dir4534565'))
True
>>> print(os.path.isdir('D:\Git_File\IAutomation\4534565'))
False
```

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a `r` character before the address string:

```
>>> os.path.isdir("D:\IAutomation\4534565")
False
>>> os.path.isdir(r"D:\IAutomation\4534565")
True
>>>
```

This `r` means `raw`. The interpreter won't consider any escape character replacement in the string.

Another example:

```
>>> print "Test\nTest"
Test
Test
>>> print r"Test\nTest"
Test\nTest
>>>
```

As you see above, in the second example, as I put a `r` before the string, the interpreter didn't replaced `\n` with a break line in the output. It consider whole the characters as raw characters.

For your case in the question, `\453` will replaced with `+` by interpreter and then the search will happen:

```
>>> print "\4534565"
+4565
>>> print r"\4534565"
\4534565
>>>
```